# Commutability of symmetric positive-definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $A, B \in R^{n \times n}$ are symmetric, positive-definite. Can we say that they commute?  If not, what additional conditions are required?

Comment: No you can't say they commute in general, you should be able to find $2 \times 2$ counterexamples very quickly. However, since you can always diagonalize such matrices [they commute iff they are simultaneously diagonalizable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675559/simultaneously-diagonalisable-iff-a-b-commute)

Comment: @Rammus, does simultaneously diagonalizable mean that they have all eigenvectors in common?

Comment: yes, it is enough to have one of them positive.